# iptables: Access single destination host without VPN

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a device where `eth0` is connected to the internet, a VPN running on `tun0` through `eth0`, and all traffic for any devices connected on `wlan0` is being routed through `tun0`.

This works great with:

```
# echo "Main"; sudo iptables -S; echo "NAT"; sudo iptables -t nat -S
Main
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
NAT
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

What I would like to do now is route traffic to one external address outside of the VPN. For instance:

```
wlan0 -> A.B.C.D -> eth0
wlan0 -> ALL OTHER HOSTS -> tun0
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables ( Netfilter ) does not manage routing , it manage filtering or alterating packets .

You need to modify your kernel route table .

In you case when the vpn is up it add a default route to go thru **tun0** , so the solution is to add another static route for **A.B.C.D**

Comment: So I did try `route add A.B.C.D dev eth0` and `route add A.B.C.D gw 192.168.0.1` to no avail. The first didn't change anything, and the second allowed me to ping A.B.C.D from the host router but cut off all access from devices connected to `wlan0`. In this setup, all trafic from `wlan0` goes through `tun0`, but none of the traffic from the host (router) does, it all goes through `eth0`. Changing the route only doesn't seem to work for connected devices. Could you supply the syntax you would recommend?

Comment: Do you have any policy routing rules in place to force traffic from wlan0 through tun0? If so you have to modify appropriate routing table and you will have to use `ip route` and not old `route` command alone.

Comment: @Fmstrat Could you possibly attach the output of  `ip route`?

Comment: `ip route`: https://pastebin.com/9NcAVFYn  You'll notice I was able to do a `sudo route add A.B.C.D dev eth0` that got me halfway there. It allows the device I'm routing on to skip the VPN when going to A.B.C.D, but devices connected via wlan0 now just can't access the host at all (while previously they could through the VPN)

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it helped me, however the final commands can be found in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

And the final answer:

```
sudo ip route add A.B.C.D dev eth0
sudo ip route add default via A.B.C.D dev eth0 table 3
sudo ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table 3
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o tun0 -d A.B.C.D -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -d A.B.C.D -j SNAT --to <IP_OF_ETH0>
sudo ip route flush cache
```

This creates the route, makes a table that's marked, and sets marked traffic to route back through.